# What are Vantages?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Sometimes on the map, I find a white circle marker, named as a Vantage. I pass by it but I cannot find anything.

For example there is one next to the quarry in Red Ridge. Do I benefit from them? Gain any experience? Are there items to find that I can sell?

Comment: @ChrisHayes I thought they were called Vantage Points?

Comment: @Vemonus IGN calls them Vantages, and other sites use Vantage Points. http://www.ign.com/wikis/horizon-zero-dawn/Vantages

Comment: @Vemonus In game I have only ever seen them called Vantages, which makes sense because they're actually Faro Vantage Spikes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Vantage Points are always high up, so you need to look around for a way to climb up. Once you reach the vantage point there is a special marker where you can press R3 and see a picture of how things used to be in the 'old days'. Also an associated audio recording. There is also a supply box nearby.

There is a trophy for finding your first vantage point and another for finding all 12 of them. You get a skill point for each set of four you collect.

Some merchants sell maps which will mark all the locations on the map.

In addition to the audio that you can play when you find the vantage point there is also a longer story in the entries for the vantage point in the Notebook. This story reveals how and why they exist.

Comment: it seems intersting , what is the reward of finding all of them ? what about the other collectibilty , such as metal flower and other ?

Comment: @Moudiz The rewards are trophies - added to answer. Possibly also a skill point on finding all twelve, but I am not sure on that. For metals flowers and the like there are trophies and you can sell sets to collectors in Meridian.

Comment: I found all of them and I don't recall getting any skill point, only the trophy.
I don't think there's any more reward apart from the interesting lore you get from the messages and pictures (and the loots boxes)

Comment: The "special merchants" in Meridian each allow for sets of a certain collectible type to be traded in for a reward.

Comment: As a tip for figuring out just how high up one of the vantage points is (some require more climbing than others), if you set a marker on the map directly on top of the vantage point, then the vertical position of the marker in the game world will actually correspond to where you need to go.

Comment: Also, because there's a supply crate next to every Vantage, you can find them pretty easily by using your Focus to locate the supply crate.

Comment: You can easily find the supply crate, but the hard part is to find the correct path to climb to reach it.